# php filehandling in a symlink doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, symlink, file-handling

I've got some trouble on a apache2 server with using symlink.

The base www folder is in "/var/www//htdocs".
I did a symlink form /home//log" to "/var/www//htdocs/l/" and called it "log".

In my oppinion, all rights are given correctly for the www-data user and the group for .

In my script, i got this error:

```
Warning: fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect.File(/var/www/<domain>/htdocs/l/log/logs_test.log) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/<domain>:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin) in /var/www/<domain>/htdocs/l/test.php on line 7 Warning: fopen(/var/www/<domain>/htdocs/l/log/logs_test.log): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/www/<domain>/htdocs/l/test.php on line 7
```

This problem should be solved when I add in the apache2.conf the real-path from the symlink. But, and this is my problem: I would not add the real-path for every symlink.

I hope you can understand my problem, if you need some more information, let me know.

Comment: Are you using a shared host? More information on [open_basedir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the problem is with the open_basedir security restrictions in PHP.  You just need to relax the restriction if you want to open files outside the specified directory tree.  Read here for more options on how to do this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: I'm using lighttpd + php-cgi also running as www-data user, but in my case, I don't have to modify the `open_basedir`. So, why in this case? Something like safe_mode?